# Does the MoneyBookers test transaction return a valid return_url with parameters or just the posted return_url value?

Tags: php, zend-framework, payment-gateway

I am new to moneybookers payment and I am doing payment test. After the payment process, I'm always returned to the stated return_url without the transaction ID that is stated in the manula. Is this because i'm using a test account? can anyone clarify the moneybookers test process? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to request a secure return url to make things work more clearly.

Comment: Hanseh Could you explain more detailed? I have the same issue with return_url parameter. The transaction id is not passed.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the status_url where it will get the payment response using $_POST. Its not visible to user but called on backend.